# How to update old model with new model with Ajax?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So far, I can list and delete a product from the cart. Upon delete, I remove the selected product and update the cart with Ajax:

`$.post("/Cart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": $(this).data('id' }`.

But, I need to update the page with ajax without postback.

Clarify: The `data` in Ajax contains the new updated cart. I just need to update the page as well somehow.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.remove-from-cart').click(function () {          

              $.post("/Cart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": $(this).data('id' },
                   function (data) {

                   // Update the page with new models(data)

                   });                
        });
    });
```

This is my ajax-function in Controllers:

```
 public List<Products> RemoveFromCart(Guid id) {

    //remove and update the cart/models

    return newCartModel;
  }
```

In View:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div>
       <label>
            @item.Name
       </label>

       //....some other property

       <button class="remove-to-cart" data-id="@item.Id">Remove from cart</button>
    </div>
    }
```

Comment: What is it that you want to update? - do you want to remove the item associated with the button you clicked (i.e. the `@item.Name` bit)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to update the content what's shown for user. When user remove a product from cart, I want ajax to update the "visual-cart" for user as well. - For your second question, my code already remove the clicked object. All what concern me is to update the View with the new model.

Comment: Your code removes the object on the server - NOT in the view. Again, if you have 5 items in the cart and you click the button to remove the 3rd one, are you wanting the view to be updated to now show only 4 items (excluding the one you just deleted)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, exactly.

Comment: OK, then your `RemoveFromCart()` method should just return `Json(true);` to indicate success (or `Json(null)` or an error code to indicate failure) and then you just remove the html associated with that button. There is no need to send back the whole list again. Give me 30 min and I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to return all the cart items back to the view again. All you need to do is remove the item associated with button you clicked from the current page.

Modify the `RemoveFromCart()` method to just return a value indicating if the item was successfully removed or not

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult RemoveFromCart(Guid id)
{
    // remove and update the cart/models
    return Json(true); // to indicate sucess
    // or return Json(null); to indicate something failed
}
```

Then in the ajax success callback, if successful, remove the associated elements from the DOM. To make selection easier, give the containing element a class name

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="item"> // add class name
        <label>@item.Name</label>
        ....
        <button class="remove-to-cart" data-id="@item.Id">Remove from cart</button>
    </div>
}

$('.remove-from-cart').click(function () {
    var container = $(this).closest('.item'); // get the 'container'       
    $.post("/Cart/RemoveFromCart", { "id": $(this).data('id' }, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            container.remove(); // remove from the DOM
        } else {
            // Oops something went wrong - display ad error message?
        }
    });                
});
```